# What is the best way to implement checking whether a username is already registered on the client side, if I want to keep my API RESTful?

Tags: rest, api, validation

As the title suggests, I am looking to have the client be able to check whether a username or email is already registered before the user submits the registration form. I had considered using an API endpoint that would return true or false for a given username, but this seems more RPC than RESTful. Is it bad practice to have such an endpoint if the rest of my API is RESTful? If so, what would a RESTful approach to this situation look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a POST /registrations and return a 400 with  validation errors array and just have client side logic filter that array for invalid username.  In other words, no reason you can't hit the endpoint multiple times.  This should help decouple your UX from your API.

Answer (score 4):

A key concept in REST is that anything that can be named can be a resource; this includes procedures. If you want to have an endpoint that accepts a username in the request body and returns true/false that's perfectly fine.

Alternatively, you can (or may already) treat a user as a resource. Take the GitHub API as an example: you can fetch a user by sending a `GET` request to [https://api.github.com/users/{username}](https://api.github.com/users/%7Busername%7D). If the user exists, and therefore the username is taken, you'll get back `200 OK`. If the user does not exist you'll get `404 Not Found`.

If you want to check if a username has been taken you can just issue a request for that username and then check the response. If you choose this approach `HEAD` is the more appropriate method. `HEAD` is essentially the same as `GET` except that the response body is empty. Since you don't need the body to determine if the user exists you can save a tiny bit of bandwidth with `HEAD` over `GET`.